# SSRS not returning values for separate fields within the report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have two fields in my report. The first is Prev Mo Hours based on the following formula: =iif(Fields!Previous.Value="Y", Fields!Mo_Base_Hrs.Value,0). Next to it is a column labeled Curr Mo Hours which uses the following formula: =iif(Fields!Current.Value="Y", Fields!Mo_Base_Hrs.Value,0).

The sum on the bottom for each of the fields is very similar. Prev Mo Hours is =sum(iif(Fields!Previous.Value = "Y",Fields!Mo_Base_Hrs.Value,Nothing)) and Curr Mo Hours is =sum(iif(Fields!Current.Value = "Y",Fields!Mo_Base_Hrs.Value,Nothing)). They both correctly sum the valuesin the report for each column.

The problem I am having is that it is only returning values for the Prev Mo Hours if the Curr Mo Hours is 0. For example, I have Employee John Smith who has Prev Mo Hours of 126.5 and Curr Mo Hours 120.5. The report only shows a value of 120.5 in the Curr Mo Hours field and 0 in the Prev Mo.

I also have Employee Allen Jones who has 41.2 Prev Mo Hours and 0 Curr Mo Hours. The correct values show up, 41.2 and 0 respectively. But again, any time I have an Employee that has Curr Mo Hours, the Prev Mo Hours show as 0.

I do not have a filter on this report. I do have sorting, but that should have no bearing. I am at a total loss. I have tried to recreate the report with a very simple table and keep getting the same problem. Can someone please help?

Here is some sample data, sample report and the fields/expressions used in the report.

[Sample_Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXADy.png)

[Sample_Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp3ZJ.jpg)

[Fields_Expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KegJb.png)

Comment: can you SHOW us what you mean rather than tell us about?

Comment: If you execute the dataset query what do the results look like, can you edit your question show an example of data that comes from your dataset.

Comment: I have updated the post with the sample data and sample report.